# .htaccess error 500 in production, not in development. Environment vars

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, environment-variables

I have a site that loads fine in my local development environment, but bombs out with `HTTP Error 500: Internal server error` in production. I don't have any access to apache error_log as it is on a shared hosting environment.

I think the issue is with setting of apache environment variables in .htaccess - possibly causing some kind of infinite loop? I require these as they are picked up by PyroCMS and used to determine environment specific settings such as DB config.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # Automatically determine and set the PYRO_ENV variable
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(localhost|local.mydomain.com|mydomain|mydomain.local)$ 
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:development,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:staging,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production,L]

    # Rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,E=PYRO_ENV:production,L]

    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg|db).*$

    # 301 permanent redirects for old web site pages
    RewriteRule ^some/old/path$ /some/new/path [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^some/other/old/path$ /some/other/new/path [R=301,L]

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

If I comment out the following lines:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
 RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production,L]
```

Then the error 500 disappears and instead I get a DB connection error (as PyroCMS cannot detect the environment).

Usually, I would set the environment variables directly into the vhost config using the `SetEnv` directive. However, as this particular site is on shared hosting, I have no access to these.

How can I resolve this issue?

On another point, I have sections below that provide 301 redirects for old website pages to new ones (this is a rebuild of an old website). My gut is telling me that even if I resolve this issue, the Environment variable that is set near the top of the .htaccess file will be lost when another `RewriteRule` is matched further down the .htaccess file. Am I correct in this thinking?

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved removing the `L` flag from the `RewriteRule`'s on that set the environment. The `L` flag was stopping further rules from being processed and invoking an infinite loop. By removing the L flag, it means that the environment is set and applies to all further redirects. This also answers my aside question about being able to persist the ENV after another 301 redirect.

```
# Automatically determine and set the PYRO_ENV variable
# We DON'T use the L flag on RewriteRule here as we want it to persist through redirects.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(localhost|local.mydomain.com|mydomain|mydomain.local)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:development]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:staging]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]
```